# My icon does not display in the browser search results. Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, browser, favicon

For the past two weeks, I've been having an issue where my icon doesn't show up in the search results of browsers, particularly on Google. The image responsible for this icon is 48px x 48px and is in PNG format. I'm using a child theme of Ocean-WP and added the icon through the theme editor in the 'Customize' section under 'Site Identity'. The icon appears correctly in the bookmark tab. Every time in the Google Search Console, I request re-indexing, so I don't know if it's a matter of time, since I can see when the site was indexed on GSC, unless the icon is independent of that. I should also add that I use the Yoast SEO plugin, where I also set the image.
The Code in head of my website looks like that:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://xyz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/cropped-Logoxyz-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" href="https://xyz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/cropped-Logoxyz-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://xyz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/cropped-Logoxyz48-180x180.png">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://xyz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/cropped-Logoxyz-270x270.png">
```

I have already tried using the SVG format and various dimensions of PNG, which were multiples of 48px. Additionally, I have primarily adhered to Google's guidelines in these attempts.
[text](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search?hl=en)